# Bug encountered When running Google's Deep Q Network Code

Tags: lua, machine-learning, deep-learning, torch

Google's Deep Q Network for Atari Games is here.

https://github.com/rahular/deepmind-dqn

When I run it with GPU setting

```
./run_gpu <game name>
```

I had this error

```html
../torch/bin/luajit: ./convnet.lua:22: attempt to call local 'convLayer' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    ./convnet.lua:22: in function 'network'
    ./NeuralQLearner.lua:89: in function '__init'
    ...einforcement_Learning/torch/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:51: in function <...einforcement_Learning/torch/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:47>
    [C]: at 0x7f419423d380
    ./initenv.lua:133: in function 'setup'
    train_agent.lua:52: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00406230
```

The code that caused this issue is in this file https://github.com/rahular/deepmind-dqn/blob/master/dqn/convnet.lua

and it is in this function

```html
function create_network(args)

    local net = nn.Sequential()
    net:add(nn.Reshape(unpack(args.input_dims)))

    --- first convolutional layer
    local convLayer = nn.SpatialConvolution

    if args.gpu >= 0 then
        net:add(nn.Transpose({1,2},{2,3},{3,4}))
        convLayer = nn.SpatialConvolutionCUDA
    end

    net:add(convLayer(args.hist_len*args.ncols, args.n_units[1],
                        args.filter_size[1], args.filter_size[1],
                        args.filter_stride[1], args.filter_stride[1],1))
    net:add(args.nl())
```

The net:add(convLayer( is 22th line.

I used gpu setting so it seems

```
convLayer =  nn.SpatialConvolutionCUDA
```

caused convLayer to be nil.

Does anyone know why nn.SpatialConvolutionCUDA returns a nil ?

Comment: Well, what is `nn.SpatialConvolutionCUDA`, and where is it set? My initial guess is that your GPU doesn't support CUDA, or at least the required version.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tested the GPU using theano so I guess it is installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did the code originally come with GPU support, or did you add it yourself?

You should replaced the depreceated layers, i.e. replace:

```
net:add(nn.Transpose({1,2},{2,3},{3,4}))
convLayer = nn.SpatialConvolutionCUDA
```

with

```
convLayer = nn.SpatialConvolution
```

Check the documentation for the layers.

Edit: Use [this branch](https://github.com/soumith/deepmind-atari), I fixed it for GPU support.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed you answered me twice.

Comment: Looks like SpatialConvolutionCUDA was deprecated: https://github.com/torch/nn/commit/025169715441bb12e40d756963c3b256dd754a54

Comment: FYI, this fork removes video output. To add it back, apply this patch to train_agent.lua: https://github.com/kuz/DeepMind-Atari-Deep-Q-Learner/commit/6c2ad94a2cbb53ec9af2ad1842c205d16932ff3e?diff=unified

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

using this github branch

https://github.com/soumith/deepmind-atari

After cloning this branch, then install cutorch and cunn using luarocks.

Now you can run the code.